# Accessing endpoint configuration from the contract

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library, channelfactory

I'm using a `ChannelFactory` inside a PCL to consume a WCF service.  My config looks something like this:

```
<client>
    <endpoint 
        address="https://www.site.com/ProductService.svc" 
        binding="customBinding" 
        contract="Interface.IProductService" 
    ...
```

And the code to consume it looks like this:

```
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);

ChannelFactory<Interface.IProductService> cf = new 
     ChannelFactory<Interface.IProductService>();
Interface.IProductService tc = cf.CreateChannel();
tc.GetProduct(1);
```

The problem that I have is that I am being asked to provide an endpoint name in nthe ChannelFactory constructor.  Is it possible to have the ChannelFactory infer the correct endpoint from the contract alone?

Comment: ooops - missed that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, no. The endpoint is the combination of the ABC, not just the contract, and you might have different endpoints for different protocols. But, unless there is some other complicating factor you haven't named, it's pretty trivial to give the endpoint the name of the contract, and just pull it by name:

```
   <client>
        <endpoint name="IProductService"
            address="https://www.site.com/ProductService.svc" 
            binding="customBinding" 
            contract="Interface.IProductService" 
        ...
```

then:

```
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);

string typeName = typeof(Interface.IProductService).Name;
ChannelFactory<Interface.IProductService> cf = new 
     ChannelFactory<Interface.IProductService>(typeName);
Interface.IProductService tc = cf.CreateChannel();
tc.GetProduct(1);
```

Of course if you're doing this for lots of services, it's not practical. But if you're doing it in the same systematic way, I've found it useful to derive those interfaces from a base Interface, and handle the whole `ChannelFactory` management problem as an intermediary `ChannelFactory<T> where T : IMyBaseContractInterface`.

Comment: My question was more: do I need an endpoint name, when I know the contract?

Comment: @pm_2 yes, because the endpoint is the combination of Address (where is the contract implementation being served up?) plus Binding (protocol plus configuration) plus Contract. The client endpoint configuration is telling your client where to look and how to communicate with the service, not to be confused with the channel, which is all about the service contracts themselves.

Comment: Okay - but I know that my contracts are unique.  I'm asking because I have seen infrastructures that infer the endpoint from the contract; I simply want to replicate this.

Comment: Unless you're talking about endpoint discovery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456792(v=vs.110).aspx) which is something quite different, I'm not familiar with any such inference.